# Why is the solution to dy/dx = y exponential?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I am trying to understand how $e$ was originally derived as a solution to the below differential:

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} = y$$

I understand how we reach:

$$y=1+x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+\dfrac{1}{6}x^3+\cdots=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$$

For my sake let's call the above solution to the differential $f(x)$ instead of $y$. It logically follows that $f(1) = e$ where $e$ is some number at which the sum converges for $x=1$. My question is why the functional form is exponential - why do we raise $e$ to $x$ as in the following?

$$f(x) = f(1)^x=e^x$$

I found this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-just-a-coincidence-that-the-derivative-of-e-x-is-also-e-x-or-is-there-some-feature-in-the-function-due-to-which-this-happens) but unfortunately got lost where the summation notation was rearranged as I'm unfamiliar with summation laws. I see we that somehow we separate out the binomial theorem from the numerators but cannot understand how this happens.

Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You show the series has all the properties of being $a^x$ for some $a$ (i.e., $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$, $f(0)=1$, $f(nx)=f(x)^n$).  Then you determine this $a$ is in fact $e=f(1)$ and write it as $e^x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the differential equation $f'(x) = f(x), f(0)=1$ to show $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$. Then $f(x) = f(1)^x$ for $x$ integer.  Then $f(x) = f(1)^x$ for $x$ rational.  And finally define irrational exponent by continuity to get $f(x) = f(1)^x$ for all $x$